# How can I run a at command with existing environmental variables and libs?

Tags: command-line, at-command

Almost a duplicate question of this [one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27289/400554), however, the answer in that post does not solve the environmental issue with `at` command.

Problem description:
I want to run my shell scripts with `at` command as a scheduled job. All my shell scripts run smoothly in a normal terminal in both Ubuntu 10.04 and 20.04 (3 different systems). I get all my results as expected. However, soon as I run my shell script with `at`, it does not run at all. Here are 3 cases to demonstrate that `at` works for simple operation and fails complex operation.

**case 1**

`at` works with simple script. Following is everything my shell `script1.sh`:

`echo $(date) > ~/Desktop/time.txt`

running `at now + 1 minutes -f ~/script1.sh`, it saves time into time.txt file. Great, it means that my `at` functions well.

**case 2**

`at` fails a simple script. Following is everything my shell `script2.sh`:

```
echo $(date) > ~/Desktop/time.txt
pycharm.sh
```

running `at now + 1 minutes -f ~/script2.sh`, it saves time into time.txt file, but the Pycharm was never opened. **However**, if I run `sh script2.sh` without using `at`, everything worked out perfectly, I get the time in time.txt file, and Pycharm opens normally. I think it simply means that `at` did not get all the variables in an existing terminal environment. Once I add `export DISPLAY=:1` to `script2.sh` as

```
echo $(date) > ~/Desktop/time.txt
export DISPLAY=:1
pycharm.sh
```

then `at now + 1 minutes -f ~/script2.sh` would function correctly.

**case 3**

I need to run the following shell script with `at` as a scheduled job, `script3.sh`:

```
gjs -numberofsplits 50 -clusterplatform condor -condorscript condor.script main.mac  > ./output0.txt 2>&1
condor_submit main.submit  > ./output1.txt 2>&1
```

Please note that all these scripts runs normally in a terminal with `sh script.sh`, **however**, running the script with `at now + 1 minutes -f ~/script3.sh`, it throws an error saved in `output0.txt` file, it says

```
gjs: error while loading shared libraries: libG4global.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I also tried to use the absolute path of gjs and condor_submit in `script3.sh` like

```
/home/albert/Products9/Gate/Gate-9.0-install/bin/gjs -numberofsplits 50 -clusterplatform condor -condorscript condor.script main.mac  > ./output0.txt 2>&1
/usr/bin/condor_submit  > ./output1.txt 2>&1
```

but it throws the same error.

---

**solutions already tried**

By far, I think the problem is well described. I think the cause of this problem is that `at` command does not have access to all the environment variables as in a normal terminal.

Here are the solutions I have tried posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89596/400554), hoping to get all environment variables exposed to `at` by adding

```
source $HOME/.profile
```

or

```
source $HOME/.bashrc
```

to the beginning of shell script. However, it does not solve or alleviate the problem at all.

**asking for help**

May I ask for help from you, the expert in this field, to solve this problem. As this problem may also trouble many other users. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons is because the `at` command scheduler is not set to run on a GUI display by default. It should work if you add `export DISPLAY=:0` to `myscrpit.sh` above the line `pycharm.py`. You can check the `DISPLAY` variable by typing `echo $DISPLAY` in a terminal window.

The other reason is the environment variables. The `$PATH` variable in cron jobs may not contain all the paths where the executables are. There may also be library files.

You can check the path for the executables by typing `which <excutable>` (e.g. `which gjs`). For the library directory the varible is `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and to see where the libraries it uses, it's `ldd $(which gjs)`.

Then add `export PATH=$PATH:<exepath>` and `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<libpath>` to your `at` scripts.

Comment: Hi @Aenfa, thank you very much for your reply. I added ````export DISPLAY=:1```` to ````myscrpit.sh```` above the line ````pycharm.sh````, it still does not work.  I don't see any difference. Meanwhile ````at```` does not work with other non-GUI programs either, like ````condor````

Comment: It could be that the path for `pycharm.sh` and `condor` are not in the `$PATH` variable when using `at`.  You can check where they are by typing `which pycharm.sh` and `which condor`. Then use the full path in the script.

Comment: You brought tons of sunshine into my day already. For ````pycharm.sh```` using the absolute path solved the problem. However, adding the absolute to ````gjs```` and ````condor_submit````  for ````condor```` has not solved the problem yet, but I think it is also very likely due to path issues. Is it possible to set it up so that ````at```` has access to normal environment variables?

Comment: See what you get by adding `> ~/Desktop/output.txt 2>&1` to the `condor` commands in the scripts then `at now -f <script>`. Let us know what error messages are in `output.txt` if any.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me debugging with great patience. Here is output.txt ````/home/user0/Products9/Gate/Gate-9.0-install/bin/gjs: error while loading shared libraries: libG4global.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory````, note that this error only happens when ````at```` is used, if I just run ````sh run_GATE.sh````, everything works out fine.

Comment: I have added to my answer.

Comment: HI Aenfa, thank you so much for your great help. My shell script calls more than ````gjs```` and ````condor````, it also invokes other programs ```` Gate```` and ````Geant4````. The error message is complaining about the absence of ````Geant4````.  I was wondering is there a generic way to add all the libraries and variables to ````at```` command, rather than add program-specific libraries.